# Absorb the excess length?

Tags: word-choice

I have a difficult time finding the right word for the following situation:

On the drawing, there are some dimensions instructed, and extra length is set for one range for workability. That extra length is “absorbed” (trimmed?) to meet the instruction. “Absorb” is the direct translation from my language, but does it make a sense?
Is there any right word for it?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you are describing. What kind of object are you working with? Is this something physical like carpentry?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, we would *define* or *specify* the dimensions.

The part to be trimmed could be called a *margin*. In some cases we might call it a *handle*, or *foot* if it is used to hold the work or attach it to a tool such as a lathe. It can also be called the *rough*, sometimes spelled as *ruff*, especially if the trimming process involves sanding or progressive removal.